# Why the differentiation of $x^{2x}$ by this process yields an erroneous result?

Tags: calculus

$y=x^{2x}$ can simply be differentiated by taking $\color{blue}{\log}$ on both sides and it gives the result $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x^{2x}(1+\ln{x})$ which makes perfect sense.

Now I'm trying to do it a little differently and it gives an erroneous result.

$y=x^{2x}=\dfrac{2x^{2x}}{2} \hspace{35pt}...(1)$

We already know, $\dfrac{d(x^{x})}{dx}=x^{x}(1+\ln{x})$ and $\dfrac{d(f(2x))}{dx}=f'(2x)\times2 \hspace{35pt}...(2)$

Using (1) and (2), $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(\frac{2x^{2x}}{2})}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{d(2x^{2x})}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\times 2x^{2x}(1+\ln{2x})\times 2=2x^{2x}(1+\ln{2x})\,.$$

Why am I getting a wrong result with this method?

Comment: $\frac{2x^{2x}}{2}$ is $\frac{2(x^{2x})}{2}$, not $\frac{(2x)^{2x}}{2}$

Comment: $f(2x) = (2x)^{2x}$ in your setup.

Comment: Suan, actually $f(2x)\neq 2x^{2x}$, indeed $f(2x)=(2x)^{2x}$.

Comment: If you feel the need to use the known derivative $(x^x)'$ you can transform your function to $y=(x^x)^2$ and then apply the rule for a derivative of composite functions.

Comment: @NDB Thanks a lot! How do I close this query?

Comment: @Swan No need. There are people without better things to do that will take care of that.